# Frontend Post with JQuery AJAX to Php Issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, query-posts, forms, wp-insert-post

My problem is the following. I'm trying to make users publish custom post_type by frontend through a form like this:

```
<form id="msform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <fieldset id="publish1" data-check-id="1">
    <input type="text" name="title" value="title"/>
    <input type="text" name="description" value="description"/>
    //some inputs
    <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Publish"/>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
```

I'm sending data from JQuery Ajax to a php file:

```
function formData() {
    var serializedValues = jQuery("#msform").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'insert.php',
        data: serializedValues,
        success: alert(serializedValues)
    });
```

so my php file looks like:

```
<?php
global $wp_query;
global $post;
//-------------------------------
$title          = $_POST['title'];
$description    = $_POST['description'];
$new_post = array(
      'post_title'    =>      $title,
      'post_content'  =>      $description,
      'post_category' =>      array(),
      'tags_input'    =>      array(),
      'post_status'   =>      'publish',
      'post_type'     =>      'my_post_type'
);
wp_insert_post($new_post); ?>
```

Now I get the alert with the serialised values but I don't know what I'm doing wrong with the php file or. It doesn't create any post. Is the `$_POST` method wrong? Or could be a problem about `insert.php` path?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest reading through [AJAX in Plugins](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) to learn how AJAX work sin WordPress.

Comment: No it is not wrong but it is also not WordPress recommend way!

Comment: Use [Debug Log](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress#WP_DEBUG_LOG) and `error_log()` to ensure you're 1) getting into the file correctly and 2) spitting out what `wp_insert_post()` returns.